# Wait for NgOnInit to complete inside ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular

I am loading some data in ngOnInit that I need to access inside of ngAfterViewInit. Specifically, Google Maps API, where I'm loading GPS coordinates from the database, then I need to add them to the map upon creation. I'm creating the map itself in ngAfterViewInit.

I guess I could move the whole thing to AfterViewInit, but I thought I'd ask if there's a good way to wait for ngOnInit to finish before using the data in AfterViewInit, in case I need it in the future for other projects.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadGpsCoordinates();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('map');
    if (elem != null) {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(elem, {
      center: { lat: -32.3881373, lng: 55.4343223 },
      zoom: 17,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    // Now loop through GPSCoordinates to add Markers
    // But wait! What if the coords aren't loaded yet?!
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming `this.loadGpsCoordinates();` returns an Observable (if not it could be made to do so)

```js
private coordinatesSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1)

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadGpsCoordinates().pipe(
    tap( data => this.coordinatesSubject.next(data))
  ).subscribe()
}

private ngAfterViewInit(data) { 
 
 this.coordinatesSubject().subscribe( data => {
    // data would be use below
    var elem = document.getElementById('map');
    if (elem != null) {
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(elem, {
        center: { lat: -32.3881373, lng: 55.4343223 },
        zoom: 17,
        disableDefaultUI: true
      });
     }
  })
}
```

Note: I didn't add a `takeUntil(destroyed$)` but you can look that up separately - it's used for unsubscribing from the service when the component is removed

Comment: getElementById won't work though, until ngAfterViewInit will it? what if the DOM's not ready yet? Would I have to set a listener, and fire it in ngAfterViewInit to let it proceed with creating the map? or vice versa on the GPS coordinates same way? It's almost like, the view has to be ready, and the gps coordinates have to be loaded, to proceed.